# Share a class in Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, sql, class, multiprocessing

My goal is to run an SQL engine in one process and the query, data entry and other actions in other at least two separate multiple processes.

I get an error with the shared variable

```
ENGINE
```

as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import time 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value, Array, RawArray


def sql(ENGINE):
    print("Starting SQL ENGINE ...")
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///TestDB.db') 
    print(f" {engine} Type: {type(engine)}")
    ENGINE.value = f"{engine}" # because of "TypeError: unicode string expected instead of instance ENGINE"
    print(ENGINE.value)

def test(ENGINE):
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        print(f" Type: {ENGINE.value}")
        print(pd.read_sql('TEST', ENGINE.value))
    except Exception as e:
        # import sys
        print(f"ERROR: {e} ")

def main():
    
    ENGINE = RawArray('u', 99) # Number is the length of the array
    p1 = Process( target=sql, args=(ENGINE, ) )
    p3 = Process( target=test, args=(ENGINE,) ) 
    p1.start()
    p3.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output (and error):

```
Starting SQL ENGINE ...
 Engine(sqlite:///TestDB.db) Type: <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>
Engine(sqlite:///TestDB.db)
 Type: Engine(sqlite:///TestDB.db)
ERROR: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'Engine(sqlite:///TestDB.db)'
```

As it it evident, the shared variable ENGINE is a string, converted from a class. I had to do this (*ENGINE.value = f"{engine}"*), because I get an error that it can't use classes as shared variable.

```
TypeError: unicode string expected instead of Engine instance
```

Is there way to either

- 1. make it to the class again or
- 2. to share a class variable

among other processes?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the engine between Processes?  Why don't you create it in the Process where it will be used?

Comment: Well that because I have multiple processes that run in parallel; SQL query, data entry and other actions in other at least two separate multiple processes. There is also a websocket that runs forever. All need to share the database! And, I want to learn more about python and how to do this specific thing.

Comment: Yes, but Processes do not share an address space.  Each Process is almost like a separate program, but with some ability to pass around some simple data structures.  A complex object, like a database engine, is unlikely to fall into this category.  If you initialize such an object in one Process, no other Process will be aware of it.  Data is typically passed between Processes by Pipes and Queues.  I haven't used sqlacademy myself, but I think it's unlikely that you can do what you want here.

Comment: Variables can be shared between processes. I can do that with strings and numbers. The database is logically on the hard drive. So any process can access that. The problem I have left is the pass on of the class as I only know how to pass on strings. So I am not sure how to share the class: "Type: <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>" properly.

Comment: Converting to string (equivalent to calling the `__str__()` method simply gives a user-friendly description of the object. It does not actually contain sufficient information to reconstruct the object. To share an object (like the database connection) the type must be pickleable. I don’t think it will be possible to share a database connection between processes. How would the database know which process to send data back to? `multiprocessing` is basically equivalent to launching multiple copies of your program.

Comment: I think your options will be to either (a) have a single process responsible for interacting with the database and extracting data into a simpler form which can be transferred between processes, or (b) have each process create its own database connection and interact separately.

Comment: A database connection is a very special type of variable, relative to more standard variables: it usually contains a socket to a database server internally. I’m not sure how one can talk about sharing a socket between processes, given that sockets are already about connecting processes…

Comment: Thanks bro. The Database is established in process 1. Another processes 2 accesses the same database that is periodically updated by process 3.  I just need to figure how to share "<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>" among processes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73112625/16310741

Comment: "I just need to figure out how to share" an instance of Engine among processes.  What we are all trying to tell you is that it probably can't be done.  Some types of objects cannot be shared like that, particularly if they contain operating system resources. You need to consider other approaches, such as the one kc9jud suggested.  Can you have a separately initialized Engine in each Process?  I would expect that they can all access the same database, which is (probably) designed to handle multiple client connections.  But kc9jud's idea would certainly work and bypass all of these problems.

Comment: Dang, hitting the limits of technology :D Cheers for elaborating bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out simply re-mounting the database for every instance is the solution!

Also this was very helpful: [Python share objects between independent processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73112625/python-share-objects-between-independent-processes)